# Symfony, how to get localized date

Tags: symfony

most likely a silly question, but I do not see how to do.

Within a controller, I need to use `$myObj->getData()->format('d-M-Y')`, and I wish to get a localized string too (in italian instead than in english).

Within a twig template, I get it by   `{{ myobj.data|localizeddate('long', 'none', app.request.locale ) }}`, but I do not know a similar trick for the former case.

---

Yes, I found how to do (thanks to  ccKep):

`$cal = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($oldObj->getData()->format('d-M-Y')." Europe/Rome");`

`$newObj->setField("my date is ". IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($cal, "d MMMM YYYY", 'it_IT')."");`

Comment: Have a look at [datefmt_format](http://php.net/manual/de/intldateformatter.format.php).

Answer (score 3):

In controller you may use Intl. For example:

```
$intl = new \IntlDateFormatter($request->getLocale(), \IntlDateFormatter::LONG, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, null, null, 'd-LLL-y');

$date = $intl->format(new \DateTime('now'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to use your code in my case; I already have a object, I need to get its date, and then to format according to a local.